# Parent and child process, socket close

Tags: sockets, process, parent-child

i am stuck by this code snippet that emulates server-client interaction,suppose that **sockfd** is a socket file descriptor created on the server side.

My question is while the parent and its child process run 'simultaneously',and during the child's execution time slice,it close the server socket **sockfd**, then when the execution flow to ,say ,the second time loop,calling the accpet function,does the parameter **sockfd** there valid,is it closed by the child process,i.e,de-allocated from the kernel file descriptor table ?

```
while (1) {
    //accept a connection from client,get the new socket from client
                       //is the sockfd valid here,is it closed by the child in
                       //the previous loop
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen); 

     if (newsockfd < 0) 
         error("ERROR on accept");
     pid = fork();
     if (pid < 0)
         error("ERROR on fork");
     if (pid == 0)  {
         close(sockfd);  // can't this cause problem ??
         dostuff(newsockfd);
         exit(0);
     }
     else close(newsockfd);
 } /* end of while */
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this piece of code:

```
if (pid == 0)  {
     close(sockfd);  // can't this cause problem ??
     dostuff(newsockfd);
     exit(0);
 }
```

the `close()` only affects the child's copy of the `sockfd` file descriptor.

The parent's copy is still open for use next time around the loop.

It's considered good manners for child processes to close unneeded inherited file descriptors.

Comment: thank you. but if i dont mis-interpret,there is only one instance of kernel file descriptor table,once the child close sockfd(it is like an index to the kernel fd table),the fd is de-allocated,then next time the parent tries to use it,can that be a problem ?

Comment: No, each process has its own fd table, starting with stdin == 0, etc.  The kernel only lets go of the socket when *no* process has it open.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing the parent does will cause the a child file descriptor to become closed in the sense that you mean. Operations on it will return appropriate status based on the situation, but that number will never be returned by `open` or `dup` until the child process calls `close`.

Comment: hi,it seems there is no child file descriptor i can see.Have i missed anything? I just doubt if that the child closes a fd which need to be used in the next loop can cause problems.Please see my last edits.Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call `fork()` function, the child process duplicates the current process. Hence in the second loop, the `sockfd` in child process is same as the parent process (which is not closed yet). So it is valid.

Comment: please see my last edits to the question.i mean is the sockfd passed to accept function valid,is it closed by the child process in the previous loop.

Answer (score 0):

It would appears that when you close the duplicated fd's, it doesn't really close the stream until all are closed. I ran into this with a just-for-fun webserver I created. I closed the fd in the fork but it stayed open.

I fixed it by closing it in the parent after the fork.